# Why minus sign is rendered differently depends on environment?

Tags: asp.net, iis

We are using soft4science equation server dll to render images based on passed in latex.
Problem is that minus sign (while part of exponent) is not clearly visible when rendered in (let's call it hosting environment A) while if I run same code locally (B) minus sign is clearly visible.
See:
[image]

This is obviously environmental issue, I've look at the fonts in environment A hoping that some fonts are missing (like Symbol Regular) but nothing seems wrong.

latex expression : `{e}^{-x}`
Environment A: Windows Server 2012

What could be the reason why this is rendered differently across different environments?

Comment: It looks like it is trying to do sub pixel rendering.

Comment: thanks, can you elaborate further? How (Can) I can control this in environment A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to speak with the developer of your LaTeX renderer.

If you look closely at the pixels, you'll see the one on the left uses only monochrome antialiasing - that would be Windows Server 2012 which by default does not use ClearType (subpixel) antialiasing, whereas the one on the right does (you can see the red/green colour-effects on the edge pixels).

Unless your LaTeX library provides a way to control text antialiasing you'll have to contact the library's developers and ask them to enable it or provide an option to enable it, otherwise it looks like its using the OS defaults.

You can enable ClearType in Windows Server 2012, but note the GUI options only control settings for your current user account, not other users.

You have two options:

#### Enable ClearType for all users by changing the default:

1. Open `regedit`
2. Go to `HKEY_USERS/.DEFAULT/Control Panel/Desktop`
3. Set these values:

   1. `FontSmoothing` REG_SZ, "`2`"
   2. `FontSmoothingType` REG_DWORD, `2`

#### Enable ClearType only for the Application Pool user:

1. Change your IIS configuration to use a dedicated User Account for your application pool instead of `NETWORK AUTHORITY` or some other built-in principal (or on Server 2012: per-site principals). Also change the application pool to enable"Load user profile".
2. Start the application pool and make some requests so the user's profile (and registry hive) is created.
3. Unload the pool and then load the user's hive file (`NTUSER.DAT`) in `regedit` and open this key:
4. Go to `HKEY_USERS/.DEFAULT/Control Panel/Desktop`
5. Set these values:

   1. `FontSmoothing` REG_SZ, "`2`"
   2. `FontSmoothingType` REG_DWORD, `2`
6. Restart the pool

Comment: 2012 server had fontsmoothing set as you suggested (talking option 1, for all users), but it still doesn't smooth font ...